# WebRTC build fails with find_depot_tools error

Tags: python, webrtc

I am trying to compile WebRTC Framework.  I cloned the repositories from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc) and [here](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src)

Prior cloning the repositories I installed depot_tools by following the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/build-webrtc-framework-yuxi-liu)

However, when I try to compile it resulted in following error

```
rk@180 src % ./tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.sh                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rameshkhanna/Documents/wRTC/webrtc/src/tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py", line 27, in <module>
    import find_depot_tools
ImportError: No module named find_depot_tools
```

I tried `pip3 install find_depot_tools` but it did not work.  Any help is highly appreciated to fix this issue

Comment: hello, I faced the same problem, did you find any solution after this post?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, this works for me

```
cd src
git checkout main
git pull origin main
tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py
```

Most likely the local version of the src cloned by you really does not contain find_depot_tools, unlike the origin/main branch